# How do I access Id and Name in combobox.SelectedItem?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, combobox

I've populated a `ComboBox` using linq. Then when I use the following code:

```
var id = combobox.SelectedItem;
```

Gives me this:

```
{ Id = 1, Name = Anthem }
```

How do I access the `Id` and `Name` separately?

Comment: Can you add how you are populating the ComboBox as well, please?

Comment: Have you tried `id.Id` and `id.Name`?

Comment: It depends on what you used to fill the ComboBox Items list. If you are using a `BindingList/List<class>`, cast `SelectedItem` to the class object: `var id = combobox.SelectedItem as [MyType];`. Then you can access the class members directly: `id.Id` and `id.Name`. Since it looks like you just want the `Id` property, you could get it directly: `var id = (combobox.SelectedItem as [MyType]).Id;`. Slightly different if the DataSource is a DataTable/DataView.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a list of anonymous type as data source, then you can use the following code to get properties of selected item:

```
dynamic item = comboBox1.SelectedItem;
var id = (int)item.Id;
var name = (string)item.Name;
```

Comment: **Note:** If you setup `ValueMember` and `DisplayMember` for the `ComboBox`, then you can also rely on `SelectedValue` property and `GetItemText` method. 

• Get selected item value property: `comboBox1.SelectedValue`
• Get selected item text property: `comboBox1.GetItemText(comboBox1.SelectedItem)`

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have bind List Of Student to comboBox with Id as ValueMember & Name as DisplayMember, then On SelectedIndexChange use following code :

```
if (combobox.SelectedValue is IConvertible)
        {
            int id = Convert.ToInt32(combobox.SelectedValue);
            string name = combobox.Text;

            // Or

            Student student = cmbCars.SelectedValue as Student;
            int idd = student.Id;
            string names = student.Name;

        }
```

This mus work !